# Source for up-to-date GPU/ASIC hash performance?

Tags: hash, sha256, argon2

I am looking for CPU, GPU and/or ASIC performance stats on hash performance. Specifically SHA256 and Argon2i. I've googled and only came up with very limited anecdotal evidence. Considering that this fast-changing field is so important for security managers, I would expect there to be a resource that provides the latest benchmarks in this area. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: how does sha2 hashing speed affect security?

Comment: @dandavis, some SHA-2 algorithms are used for password hashing, with a tuneable number of iterations. Without knowing how fast a dictionary attack can be, it’s hard to know how many iterations you need.

Comment: A well implemented system that uses pw-based security will use a system of hashing whereas the password and a salt are hashed many thousands of times ("work factor") before they are stored. The idea is that if these pw-hashes are obtained by an attacker, it will require a lot of CPU work/time to brute-force all the passwords from these hashes.

Knowing the GPU/ASIC speed of brute-forcing is helpful in designing security policies––especially password expiration policies.

Comment: It is now 2 years 1 month since this was asked; a google search still fails to turn up much of use. Did you ever manage to find anything? It is hard to believe that there is simply no information on this.

Answer (score 3):

In June 2016, [Jeremi M. Gosney](https://twitter.com/jmgosney) (the guy behind [sagitta HPC](https://sagitta.pw/)) published the results obtained with their top-end password cracker, running Hashcat v3.00-beta: https://gist.github.com/epixoip/a83d38f412b4737e99bbef804a270c40

This list contains all hashing functions implemented by Hashcat which, unfortunately, doesn't support Argon2i [yet](https://twitter.com/hashcat/status/724710087730814981).

Regarding SHA256, the results are:

```
Speed.Dev.#1.:  2865.2 MH/s (96.18ms)
Speed.Dev.#2.:  2839.8 MH/s (96.65ms)
Speed.Dev.#3.:  2879.5 MH/s (97.14ms)
Speed.Dev.#4.:  2870.6 MH/s (96.32ms)
Speed.Dev.#5.:  2894.2 MH/s (96.64ms)
Speed.Dev.#6.:  2857.7 MH/s (96.78ms)
Speed.Dev.#7.:  2899.3 MH/s (96.46ms)
Speed.Dev.#8.:  2905.7 MH/s (96.26ms)
Speed.Dev.#*.: 23012.1 MH/s
```

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely the "limited anecdotal evidence" I was speaking of =)

Comment: I see... Well, I don't think it has been much advancement since then. The GTX 1080 remains the top-notch GPU today. You might ask on Hashcat forums or Jeremy directly. Please keep us posted if you find anything interesting :)